# Existence of sequence with unity norm such that the distance between any two in norm sense is always greater than 1.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be infinite dimensional normed linear space. Then prove that there exist a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|x_n-x_m\|>1$ for all $n,m=1,2,...,n!=m$.

Can this be solved by using the riesz lemma?

Comment: Yes, use the Riesz lemma and construct the sequence recursively.

Comment: Can you please provide some hints. Thank you

Comment: Is this for a Banach space? You did not say.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It is for any normed linear space